# Android Vector class, should I use "new" or "clear()"?

Tags: java, android, vector

I am creating a game application where you climb up "stars".

I want my vector object to hold on to the top most "stars".

So my grapTopMostStars method calls .clear() for the vector object that it uses then grasps the top most stars.

However my good friend told me that why not just declare new Vector object since I don't really care about previous stars that were in my Vector.

He sounds valid but I am worried since I am making this game on mobile that somehow creating new instances many times will slow down my application.

Comment: You should better be thinking about replacing the `Vector`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clear` internally calls `removeAllElements` which is implemented as follows:

```
  651       public synchronized void removeAllElements() {
  652           modCount++;
  653           // Let gc do its work
  654           for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
  655               elementData[i] = null;
  656   
  657           elementCount = 0;
  658       }
```

Iterating the vector to set every entry to `null` is definitely more overhead than just creating a new Vector.

By the way you should replace your `Vector` by an `ArrayList` if possible. The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#clear%28%29) tells us:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to
>   implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java
>   Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations,
>   Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed,
>   it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

(thread-safe stuff is slower than unsynchronized non-thread-safe classes.)

Comment: Ty! good to know that I need to use ArrayList!